Counting the number of rectangles whose vertices are among those of a regular polygon
Let $P$ be a regular polygon with $n$ sides inscribed in a circle.

Suppose there exists a rectangle, all of whose vertices are
among the vertices of $P$. Then show that $n$ must be an
even number.

proof- assume there exist odd $n$ such that we can find a rectangle satisfying the hypothesis. A rectangle has a property that $180$ rotation will be same as original looking at center of dihedral group $D_{2n}$, we have  center $Z(D_{2n})=\{e\}.$
hence rectangle $180$ degree rotation is not available , which show $n$ is odd is impossible. $\square$

Suppose $n = 2m$. Calculate the number of rectangles
having all their vertices among the vertices of $P$.

We have to choose $2$ vertices to make a rectangle, as it will force us to choose the vertices  diagonally opposite to choosen vertices(because 180 degree rotation will preserve them ) and we have 4 sides in a rectangle, so we have $\frac14{2m \choose 2}$ ways.
Is this correct?

No, the second vertex can't be the one opposite the first

i meant diagonally opposite

If $2m=4$, so you have a square, you should get one way, but your formula gives $1.5$ ways.

i understood my mistake , it should be  ${m \choose 2}$

For $n$, odd rectangles cannot exist.
Proof: Suppose $ABCD$ was a rectangle whose vertices were vertices of the regular $n$-gon. Then by Thales's theorem, $AC$ must be a diameter of the circle. This is impossible if there are an odd number of vertices on the polygon.
Supppse $n=2m$ is even.
Note that $ABCD$ is a rectangle iff AC and BD are distinct diameters of the circle. There are $m$ distinct diameters of the circle. This means there are $\binom m2$ ways of choosing 2 distinct diameters which means there are $\binom m2$ distinct rectangles that can be made by choosing 4 vertices of the $n$-gon.

i wanted to know about my proof

You must not choose 2 opposite vertices for the first 2 corners.

no i want to know about 1st one ,

1st proof seems to be correct
